# any FAST tex to html program?

Tags: html, latex, debian

(im using debian squeeze)

i tried **catdvi** (but its unacceptable - just a lot of '?'s)

now i am using **tex4ht** but its awfully sloow..

for example generating html for this : [image: eq]
takes ~2 seconds (thats 4+ times slower than generating the image !!!)

1. is there something wrong with my config or is tex4ht really that slow?
2. (i doubt theres something wrong with my config) are there any other(FAST) reliable tex2html converters?

Comment: of course i am using a cacher but still 2 seconds is too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already suggested, if you want equations in a web page, [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) will process TeX math code into proper math display.

Comment: thats a nice script, however i want to statically generate html. but if all fails ill use this one ...

Comment: You can already [copy the MathML code from the MathJax output](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/copy-and-paste/). Surely there is a way to do that in code and export it to a file without human intervention :)

Comment: If you want it static why are you worried about speed?

Comment: because users could hog the site when creating new posts... ill end up using MathJax so i accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

What about [latex2html](http://www.uibk.ac.at/th-physik/howto/latex2html.html)? It seems the only hit on Google that provides this kind of functionality. Keep in mind that latex is inherently slow, and it may be better to rely on something MathML or MathJax related. I have not tested the above for performance.

On Debian squeeze, just do

```
apt-get install latex2html
```

Comment: latex2html just generates images, etc etc and puts them in a html file... i want something that generates html, as short small as possible, as human readable as possible, not a html page ;/ and its slower than tex4ht